# How to discuss sick leave with prospective employers during job hunt?

Tags: job-search, sickness

I am currently on medical sick leave due to anxiety related to my job. Additionally, I am searching for new jobs and have a couple conversations about this.

My question is: how can I explain to a perspective employer that I am on sick leave when job hunting?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question.  You seem to be implying that your manager involuntarily put you on sick leave.  That would be very odd and if that's the case you should make that explicit in your question (or clarify what "sends somebody on sick leave" means).  But then you seem to imply that there was a legitimate reason for you to request the leave to deal with anxiety issues.  But why would a potential new employer even need to know that you're currently on sick leave?

Comment: Why do you think they need to know?

Comment: Hi Monoandale, I edited this somewhat significantly to focus on the core question. If you can [edit] why you think potential employers will either know or think this important that would help clarify!

Comment: Thanks enderland, I think that your editing helped clean the question.

Comment: Hi, but if I interview during sick leave, won't this come out sooner or later at my new job? 'oh, you said you wanted a new challenge but the situation was screwed up and you were even sick, what a troublemaker!'

Comment: I am away for a few weeks, if the new employer makes me an offer and has to contact HR they will find out that I was away on sick leave...

Comment: @Monoandale Is the *reason* for your sick leave on the HR record? If so, what is the reason listed there? I would be surprised if the HR recorded your reason as "anxiety related to this job". :)

Answer (score 4):

> how can I explain to a perspective employer that I am on sick leave
>   when job hunting?

You don't.

I assume whatever leave arrangement you have with your current employer ends as soon as you are no longer employed there. Thus, your current sick leave has no impact at all on your next employer. You start there anew.

If I am incorrect, and you are planning to start a new job, yet remain out sick, then you must explain this early in the interview process. Few employers would have provisions for such a situation, so you must seek an employer who would be willing to accommodate your special needs.